# ExpandableListView Not Expanding?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Hello I've been trying for expandable listview in my application. The issue is that I could get the parentList, but on selection  of Parent Item the child view doesn't expand/show.Below is my code.
can anyone please help me out in solving this issue, I've tried the focusable code in xml but didnt't work.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:gravity="top"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!--   <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/fee_term_check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/sampleDimension10"
    android:layout_weight="0"
 />    -->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fee_schedule_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/sampleDimension"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fee_schedule_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/sampleDimension10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/sampleDimension"
        android:text="term"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total_termfee"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Term Fee"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
public class Expandable extends AppCompatActivity {

ExpandableListView expandableRecyclerview;
ExpandableAdapter expandableAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
String feeMonthUrl = "http://35.196.219.109/webapi/newStudentPayment/getStudentPaymentDetails/155/4";
/*List<FeeMonth> feeMonths = null;
List<FeeTermDetailsData> dummyFeeType = null;
List<FeeTermDetailsData> feeTermDetailsDataList = null;*/

ArrayList<FeeMonth> feeMonths = new ArrayList<FeeMonth>();
List<StudentFeeScheduleData> feeScheduleData = new ArrayList<StudentFeeScheduleData>();
List<FeeTermDetailsData> feeTermDetailsDataList = new ArrayList<FeeTermDetailsData>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<FeeTermDetailsData>> dummyfeeType = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.expandable_recyclerview);


    expandableRecyclerview = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_recyclerview);


    dummyfeeType = new ArrayList<ArrayList<FeeTermDetailsData>>();

    Log.i("dummyyyyyy", dummyfeeType.toString());

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(feeMonthUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //p.dismiss();
            try {
                FeeMonth feeMonth = new FeeMonth();
                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("response");
                Log.i("mainObject", jsonObject.toString());

                feeMonth.setYearId(jsonObject.getString("educationalYearId"));
                Log.i("idddddd", jsonObject.getString("educationalYearId"));

                JSONArray studentFeePlanwithAmount = jsonObject.getJSONArray("studentFeePlanWithAmounts");
                Log.i("feePlanAmount", studentFeePlanwithAmount.toString());
                dummyfeeType = new ArrayList<ArrayList<FeeTermDetailsData>>();
                for (int i = 0; i < studentFeePlanwithAmount.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject studentFeePlanObject = studentFeePlanwithAmount.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONObject studentFeePlanAmountId = studentFeePlanObject.getJSONObject("studentFeePlanWithAmountId");
                    feeMonth.setStudentFeePlanWithAmountId(studentFeePlanAmountId.getInt("id"));

                    feeMonth.setName(studentFeePlanObject.getString("feePlanName"));
                    feeMonth.setTotalYearFee(studentFeePlanObject.getString("totalPayableAmount"));
                    Log.i("feeMonthhhhh", feeMonths.toString());

                    JSONArray feePlanSchedule = studentFeePlanObject.getJSONArray("studentFeePlanScheduleWithAmounts");

                    //studentFilterSchedule(7, feePlanSchedule);

                    for (int j = 0; j < feePlanSchedule.length(); j++) {
                        StudentFeeScheduleData studentFeeScheduleData = new StudentFeeScheduleData();
                        JSONObject termsObject = feePlanSchedule.getJSONObject(j);

                        JSONObject feePlanScheduleId = termsObject.getJSONObject("studentFeePlanScheduleWithAmountId");
                        studentFeeScheduleData.setFeePlanScheduleId(feePlanScheduleId.getInt("id"));

                        //JSONObject feePlanId = termsObject.getJSONObject("feePlanId");
                        //studentFeeScheduleData.setFeePlanId(feePlanId.getInt("id"));
                        studentFeeScheduleData.setTerms(termsObject.getString("feePlanScheduleName"));
                        studentFeeScheduleData.setTotalTermFee(termsObject.getDouble("duesFeeForSchedule"));
                        Log.i("feeMonthsss", feeMonth.toString());

                        JSONArray feePlanTypeDetailsArray = termsObject.getJSONArray("feeTypePerScheduleAmountList");

                        for (int k = 0; k < feePlanTypeDetailsArray.length(); k++) {


                            FeeTermDetailsData feeTermDetailsData = new FeeTermDetailsData();
                            JSONObject feeScheduleTypeDetails = feePlanTypeDetailsArray.getJSONObject(k);

                            JSONObject feeTypeId = feeScheduleTypeDetails.getJSONObject("feeTypePerScheduleAmountId");
                            feeTermDetailsData.setFeeTypeId(feeTypeId.getInt("id"));

                            JSONObject feeTypePlanScheduleId = termsObject.getJSONObject("studentFeePlanScheduleWithAmountId");
                            feeTermDetailsData.setFeePlanScheduleId(feeTypePlanScheduleId.getInt("id"));

                            feeTermDetailsData.setFeeTypeName(feeScheduleTypeDetails.getString("feeTypeName"));
                            feeTermDetailsData.setFeeTypeAmount(feeScheduleTypeDetails.getInt("amount"));

                            Log.i("feeTypeeee", feeTermDetailsDataList.toString());
                            Log.i("feeTypeeee",feeTermDetailsData.toString());
                            dummyfeeType.add(feeTermDetailsData);
                            Log.i("dummydataaa", jsonObject.toString());

                        }

                        feeScheduleData.add(studentFeeScheduleData);
                    }

                    /*JSONArray feePlanTypeDetailsArray= studentFeePlanObject.getJSONArray("feePlanTypeWithAmountList");
                    for (int k=0; k<feePlanTypeDetailsArray.length();k++){
                        FeeTermDetailsData feeTermDetailsData= new FeeTermDetailsData();
                        JSONObject feeTypeDetails= feePlanTypeDetailsArray.getJSONObject(k);
                        feeTermDetailsData.setFeeTypeName(feeTypeDetails.getString("feeTypeName"));
                        feeTermDetailsData.setFeeTypeAmount(feeTypeDetails.getInt("amount"));
                        feeTermDetailsDataList.add(feeTermDetailsData);
                        Log.i("feeTypeeee",feeTermDetailsDataList.toString());
                    }*/


                    JSONObject feePlanId = studentFeePlanObject.getJSONObject("feePlanId");
                    feeMonth.setFeePlanId(feePlanId.getInt("id"));

                    Log.i("monthhh", feeMonths.toString());

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i("finalDummyData", dummyfeeType.toString());
            Log.i("finalFeeScheduleData", dummyfeeType.toString());
            expandableAdapter = new ExpandableAdapter(Expandable.this, feeScheduleData, dummyfeeType);
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Expandable.this);
            //expandableRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            expandableRecyclerview.setAdapter(expandableAdapter);



            /*expandableRecyclerview.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(Expandable.this, "doing well", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            expandableRecyclerview.getExpandableListAdapter();

           /* expandableRecyclerview.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(Expandable.this, "its expanding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            expandableRecyclerview.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(Expandable.this, "collapsing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });*/

        }


    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    mySingleton.getInstance(Expandable.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
}
```

MyAdapter Class:

```
   public class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
Context context;
ExpandableAdapter expandableAdapter;
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<StudentFeeScheduleData> feeScheduleList = new ArrayList<StudentFeeScheduleData>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<FeeTermDetailsData>> feeTermDetailsDataList;

public ExpandableAdapter(Context context, List<StudentFeeScheduleData> feeScheduleList,
                         ArrayList<ArrayList<FeeTermDetailsData>> feeTermDetailsDataList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.feeScheduleList = feeScheduleList;
    this.feeTermDetailsDataList = feeTermDetailsDataList;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return feeScheduleList.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    System.out.println("lisss" + feeTermDetailsDataList.toString());
    //return feeTermDetailsDataList.get(groupPosition).size();
    return ((ArrayList<FeeTermDetailsData>) feeTermDetailsDataList.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return feeScheduleList.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return feeTermDetailsDataList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_feeschedule_item, null);
    }
    StudentFeeScheduleData feeMonth = (StudentFeeScheduleData) getGroup(groupPosition);

    /*ExpandableListView expandableListView= (ExpandableListView) parent;
    expandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);*/

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.feeSchedule = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fee_schedule_item);
    holder.dueAmount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.total_termfee);
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.feeSchedule.setText(feeMonth.getTerms());
    String textAmount = String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(feeMonth.getTotalTermFee()));
    holder.dueAmount.setText(textAmount);


    return convertView;

}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    FeeTermDetailsData feeTermDetailsData = (FeeTermDetailsData) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fee_schedule_detailview, null);
    }
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.feeTypeName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fee_schedule_item);
    holder.feeTypeAmount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.total_termfee);
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.feeTypeName.setText(feeTermDetailsData.getFeeTypeName());
    String textAmount = String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(feeTermDetailsData.getFeeTypeAmount()));
    holder.feeTypeAmount.setText(textAmount);
    return convertView;

}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView feeSchedule, dueAmount, feeTypeName, feeTypeAmount;
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    //getChild(0,groupPosition);
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}
}
```

fee_schedule_detailview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fee_type_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/sampleDimension"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Transportation"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/sampleDimension"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=":"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fee_type_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/sampleDimension"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="@dimen/sampleDimension"
        android:text="500"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Mylog for List:

```
04-26 12:05:53.690 28710-28710/com.example.sairam.dummy I/System.out: 
lisss[FeeTermDetailsData{feeTypeName='TUTION FEE', feeTypeAmount=35160, 
feeTypeId=573, feePlanScheduleId=219}, FeeTermDetailsData{feeTypeName='MESS 
FEE', feeTypeAmount=0, feeTypeId=574, feePlanScheduleId=219}, 
FeeTermDetailsData{feeTypeName='TUTION FEE', feeTypeAmount=26370, 
feeTypeId=575, feePlanScheduleId=220}, FeeTermDetailsData{feeTypeName='MESS 
FEE', feeTypeAmount=0, feeTypeId=576, feePlanScheduleId=220}, 
FeeTermDetailsData{feeTypeName='TUTION FEE', feeTypeAmount=26370, 
feeTypeId=577, feePlanScheduleId=221}, FeeTermDetailsData{feeTypeName='MESS 
FEE', feeTypeAmount=0, feeTypeId=578, feePlanScheduleId=221}]
04-26 12:05:53.691 28710-28710/com.example.sairam.dummy I/System.out: 
lisss[FeeTermDetailsData{feeTypeName='TUTION FEE', feeTypeAmount=35160, 
feeTypeId=573, feePlanScheduleId=219}, FeeTermDetailsData{feeTypeName='MESS 
FEE', feeTypeAmount=0, feeTypeId=574, feePlanScheduleId=219}, 
FeeTermDetailsData{feeTypeName='TUTION FEE', feeTypeAmount=26370, 
feeTypeId=575, feePlanScheduleId=220}, FeeTermDetailsData{feeTypeName='MESS 
FEE', feeTypeAmount=0, feeTypeId=576, feePlanScheduleId=220}, 
FeeTermDetailsData{feeTypeName='TUTION FEE', feeTypeAmount=26370, 
feeTypeId=577, feePlanScheduleId=221}, FeeTermDetailsData{feeTypeName='MESS 
FEE', feeTypeAmount=0, feeTypeId=578, feePlanScheduleId=221}]
```

Comment: post `student_feeschedule_item.xml`

Comment: I have edited the question and updated the student_feeschedule_item.xml and fee_schedule_detailview.xml also

Comment: I can't see any issues in your code. did you check the child count `return ((ArrayList<FeeTermDetailsData>) feeTermDetailsDataList.get(groupPosition)).size();
`

Comment: I've observed in debug mode that the data is not passed on the childview but  displays the data in log file on touching the parent item. I don't understand why its not expanding and displaying

Comment: What is the getchildcount() method returns? And check my answer. You have mistakenly called getgroup()

Answer (score 0):

In your **`getChildView() method`** , You have mistakenly called `getGroup(groupPosition)` which is not the instance of FeeTermDetailsData

Replace

```
FeeTermDetailsData feeTermDetailsData = (FeeTermDetailsData) getGroup(groupPosition);
```

As

```
FeeTermDetailsData feeTermDetailsData = (FeeTermDetailsData) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
```

Comment: are you getting any error, Please log your list size

Comment: I'm not getting any errors and I've updated with log file of list after parent item click